# How to pass variables in Graphql Apollo Query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have the following query and i would like it to return the items with a specific parent name

```
query categorias ($name: String) {
  categories(level: 1, first: 13 ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        level
        parent {
          name: $name
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can't quite understand how to make this work. I've tried the following as well but "it's not a valid argument"

```
    query categorias ($name: String) {
      categories(level: 1, first: 13 ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
            level
            parent (name:$name{
              name
            }
            }
          }
        }
      

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `name` variable to the actual query i.e `categories`.Not sure what the schema is but the basic idea is below. `categorias` is the name given by you (so that you can use multiple queries) not the actual query. Something like this.

```
query categorias ($name: String) {
  categories(name: $name, level: 1, first: 13 ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        level
        parent {
          name: $name
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```